# PostgreSQL: Grant CRUD operations only in one database

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to grant CRUD operations to a user ONLY on a specific database?
Let's asume there are 2 databases on my server: `database_allowed` and `database_forbiden`

I have created a user on postgreSQL, and granted this privileges:

```
CREATE ROLE crud_user LOGIN PASSWORD '###';


--Next commands are executed connected to the database
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_allowed TO crud_user ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO crud_user;
```

However, after executing the commands, I only get an error:

> FATAL: role "crud_user" is not permitted to log in

I know I can execute: `ALTER ROLE crud_user WITH LOGIN`, but, despite the user can only execute CRUD operations on `database_allowed`, he can connect both, and see tablenames, etc...

Is there a way to prevent granting login on all databases?

Comment: Did you `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE database_forbidden FROM PUBLIC`?

Comment: @Bergi that did trick. It's a bit confusing that, by default, he can login all databases and we have to revoke connect on each one. It's seems more logical denny by default. Anyway, If you post the comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `crud_user` can access the other database because of its `PUBLIC` permissions:

> PostgreSQL grants privileges on some types of objects to `PUBLIC` by default when the objects are created. No privileges are granted to `PUBLIC` by default on tables, table columns, sequences, foreign data wrappers, foreign servers, large objects, schemas, or tablespaces. For other types of objects, the default privileges granted to `PUBLIC` are as follows: `CONNECT` and `TEMPORARY` (create temporary tables) privileges for databases; `EXECUTE` privilege for functions and procedures; and `USAGE` privilege for languages and data types (including domains). The object owner can, of course, `REVOKE` both default and expressly granted privileges.
>
> <sup>([Postgres documentation *Privileges*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html))</sup>

So you'll want to run

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE database_forbidden FROM PUBLIC
```